# Implementing a Queue where you can insert elements at a specific position while enqueuing/dequeuing in constant time?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

Sample input:

```
2
3 101 102 103
3 201 202 203
ENQUEUE 101
ENQUEUE 201
ENQUEUE 102
ENQUEUE 202
ENQUEUE 103
ENQUEUE 203
DEQUEUE
DEQUEUE
DEQUEUE
DEQUEUE
DEQUEUE
DEQUEUE
STOP
```

First line = Number of "groups", N

Following N lines = First number is # of elements in the group K, following K numbers are the elements themselves (in the range 0...999999)

All lines until a STOP input = Either an Enqueue or Dequeue query. If Enqueue, you're queuing the element currently being processed, E, at either A. at the end of the queue if there's no element in the queue that belongs to the same "group" as E or B. right behind the last element which belongs to the same "group" as E

Dequeue is straightforward, just remove the first element from the queue. For every Dequeue query, output the element that is dequeued.

Enqueuing and dequeuing of an element should only take **constant time**

Output would be:

```
101
102
103
201
202
203
```

I'm initially thinking about some kind of a 2D nested structure, like an array of Queues or something, but enqueueing/dequeueing wouldn't take constant time, so I'm not sure.

Also, the fact that I'm given the elements themselves before the queries should be a hint, but towards what I'm not sure.

Comment: It is unclear a) what should happen with numbers absent in the groups (say, `302`) and b) what should happen if groups overlap (say, the second line reads `3 101 102 203`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* groups don't intersect, elements from every group are always clustered together. In other words, you have a queue of queues:

- For every group, create an (initially empty) queue;
- Create an index structure for a constant-time search of the group corresponding to the number entered (brute force solution is an array with 1000000 references, can change to HashSet);
- Create a queue of queue references ("main" queue).

Now for `ENQUEUE X`

- Find the corresponding queue for `X`;
- Add `X` to it; if it was empty, enqueue the queue into the main queue.

For `DEQUEUE`

- Take the first queue in the main queue, dequeue element from it;
- If it's empty, dequeue the queue from the main queue.

Comment: That Enqueue process would be done in constant time? Isn't finding the corresponding queue for X already O(n)?

Comment: The X to queue structure would be a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or simply an array from [0..maxval-minval].  Either would be O(1)lookup.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** 
1. One Element belongs to one group only.
2. ENQUEUE query will contain data that has entry in one group.

**Code:**

```
public class Queue {
    private static final BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private static int noOfGroups = 0;
    private static int totalNumberOfElements = 0;
    private static HashMap<String, Element> elementsMap = new HashMap<String, Element>();
    private static HashMap<Integer, Group> groupsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Group>();
    private static Element queueStart = null;
    private static Element queueEnd = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        getInput(InputType.NO_OF_GROUP, null);
        for (int groupId = 0; groupId < noOfGroups; ++groupId) {
            getInput(InputType.GROUP_ENTRY, groupId);
        }
        if (elementsMap.size() != totalNumberOfElements) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Note: Same element found on different groups. Group that entered later will be considered.");
        }
        String query;
        while (!"STOP".equals(query = getInput(InputType.QUERY_ENTRY, null))) {
            if (query.equals("DEQUEUE")) {
                Element element = processDEQUEUE();
                if (element != null) {
                    // output the element that is dequeued.
                    output.append(element.getData()).append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            } else {
                processENQUEUE(query);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Result:");
        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private static void processENQUEUE(String data) {
        Element currentElement = elementsMap.get(data);
        if (currentElement != null) {

            int groupId = currentElement.getGroupId();
            Group currentGroup = groupsMap.get(groupId);

            if (currentGroup.getLast() == null) {
                // Case A:
                // queuing the element "data" at the end of the queue if there's no
                // element in the queue that belongs to the same "group" as "data"
                currentGroup.setLast(currentElement);
                if (queueStart == null) {
                    queueStart = currentElement;
                }
                if (queueEnd == null) {
                    queueEnd = currentElement;
                } else {
                    queueEnd.setNext(currentElement);
                    queueEnd = currentElement;

                }

            } else if (currentGroup.getLast() != null) {
                // Case B:
                // queuing the element "data" right behind the last element which
                // belongs to the same "group" as "data"
                currentElement.setNext(currentGroup.getLast().getNext());
                currentGroup.getLast().setNext(currentElement);
                currentGroup.setLast(currentElement);

            }

        } else {
            System.err.println("Cannot process enqueue for " + data + ". There is no group that contains this data.");
        }

    }

    private static Element processDEQUEUE() {
        Element element = null;
        // removing the first element from the queue.
        if (queueStart == null) {
            System.err.println("Cannot process dequeue. Queue is empty.");
        } else {
            element = queueStart;
            queueStart = queueStart.getNext();
        }
        return element;
    }

    private static String getInput(InputType inputType, Integer groupId) throws IOException {
        boolean isValidInput = false;
        String input = null;
        String message = null;
        String returnValue = null;
        while (!isValidInput) {
            switch (inputType) {
            case NO_OF_GROUP:
                System.out.println("Number of \"groups\": ");
                break;
            case GROUP_ENTRY:
                System.out.println("Group-" + groupId + " Entry: ");
                break;
            case QUERY_ENTRY:
                System.out.println("Query: ");
            }
            input = BR.readLine();
            switch (inputType) {
            case NO_OF_GROUP:
                try {
                    noOfGroups = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    isValidInput = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    message = ex.getMessage();
                    isValidInput = false;
                }
                break;
            case GROUP_ENTRY:
                try {
                    String groupInputElements[] = input.split(" ");
                    int noOfElements = 0;

                    noOfElements = Integer.parseInt(groupInputElements[0]);
                    if (groupInputElements.length != noOfElements + 1) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expecting " + noOfElements + " elements. Found "
                                + (groupInputElements.length - 1) + " elements.");
                    }
                    groupsMap.put(groupId, new Group());
                    for (int index = 1; index < groupInputElements.length; ++index) {
                        Element element = new Element();
                        element.setGroupId(groupId);
                        element.setData(groupInputElements[index]);
                        elementsMap.put(groupInputElements[index], element);
                    }
                    totalNumberOfElements += noOfElements;
                    isValidInput = true;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    message = ex.getMessage();
                    isValidInput = false;
                }
                break;
            case QUERY_ENTRY:
                try {
                    if (!input.contains("ENQUEUE") && !input.equals("DEQUEUE") && !input.equals("STOP")) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Query can only be ENQUEUE, DEQUEUE or STOP");
                    } else if (input.contains("ENQUEUE")) {
                        String[] enqueueData = input.split(" ");
                        if (enqueueData.length != 2) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                    "Invalid Data. Expected format: ENQUEUE <DATA>\t\tExample: ENQUEUE 101");
                        }
                        returnValue = enqueueData[1];
                    } else {
                        returnValue = input;
                    }
                    isValidInput = true;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    message = ex.getMessage();
                    isValidInput = false;
                }
            }
            if (message != null) {
                System.err.println(message);
                message = null;
            }

        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}

enum InputType {
    NO_OF_GROUP, GROUP_ENTRY, QUERY_ENTRY
}

class Element {
    private Element next;
    private int groupId;
    private String data;

    public Element getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Element next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Group {

    public Element getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(Element last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    private Element last;
}
```

**Result:**
[image]